# Bug when managing whole numbers using C++ and VS2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I was debugging a C++ program and I found out that, for some reason, under my version of visual studio 2008, some numbers dont seem to be stored correctly. For example,number -3254535440 seems to be stored as 1040431856. These numbers are small enough to be stored into a long long, so there should be no problem. If I run the following code, both error messages are displayed. I have tried on two different machines. Any idea? Thanks!

```
if (-3254535440 == 1040431856)
    printf("ERROR\n");

long long j = -3254535440;
if (j == 1040431856)
    printf("ERROR2\n");
```

Tested under Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP

Answer (score 4):

The literals are still `int`s. You need to make them a larger type:

```
long long j = -3254535440LL;
```

That doesn't fit into a 32-bit type (which it seems your `int` is), but once represented as a `long long`, it keeps its value.

Comment: Am I crazy or does §2.14.2 not suggest that having no suffix will pick the smallest type that fits the value, including `long long int`?

Comment: @sftrabbit, It could have something to do with the fact that `long long` wasn't actually a type until C++11, but I'd say so, yes. I'm not sure what is meant by extended type, but if it doesn't fit into any types, it's allowed to use one of those. I'm guessing that includes an implementation-defined `long long` type. However, I'm not sure why it wouldn't be used then.

Comment: @sftrabbit, In case you haven't seen, the other answer says it all. It fits into `unsigned int`, causing the negation to result in a different positive value.

Answer (score 2):

Compile with a higher warning level and you'll get a warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long j = -3254535440;
    printf("%lld\n",j);
}
```

Compiler:

```
c:\>cl /nologo /W4 test.cpp
test.cpp
test.cpp(5) : warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned

c:\>test
1040431856
```

As others mentioned, declare a long long literal instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long j = -3254535440LL;
    printf("%lld\n",j);
}
```

Result:

```
c:\>cl /nologo /W4 test.cpp
test.cpp

c:\>test
-3254535440
```

Comment: Why didn't I realize that fit into an unsigned 32-bit type? That makes so much more sense.

Comment: Yes, if the number was bigger than unsigned 32-bit, it will work even without LL.  The compiler will recognize it as long long.

Comment: Does VS2008 do that, seeing as how it's not C++11 with it's standard `long long` type?

Comment: I don't have it installed anymore, but I believe it did.  It still had `__int64` and friends and supported `LL`.